# OLS panel vector autoregression with exogenous variables

Tags: r, python, panel-data, stata, vector-autoregression

Are there any R, Stata, or Python packages that allow the estimation of panel VARX models with options to specify fixed-effects and clustered standard errors?

I'm quite desperate at this point and I hope there's a package somewhere I missed.